# re#er shortcut - show a list of interface implementationsi

Tags: resharper

I have a method `void abc(IAnimal animal)`. When I type in another method `abc(` how do I make ReSharper show a list of objects implementing IAnimal?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my installation CTRL-ALT-B gives you a list of implementations of an interface.